# Using x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Type in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, json, .net-4.0, urlencode

I'm writing a .NET client for [Menalto Gallery 3](http://gallery.menalto.com/), which uses a RESTful JSON API (see [API docs](http://codex.gallery2.org/Gallery3%3aAPI%3aREST)). I decided to use WCF for my client and it looks like it could greatly simplify my work, were it not for the fact that there's one method that requires a Content-Type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`.

I have seen various *hacks* to send urlencoded data from WCF, for example by [using a Stream parameter](http://blogs.southworks.net/erossetto/2007/09/03/raw-http-post-with-wcf/) which enables me to send arbitrary data, but still requires an `IClientMessageInspector` to set the Content-Type:

```
internal class GalleryClientMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector {
  public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel) {
    HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestMessage =
      getOrAddRequestMessageProperty(request);

    if (/* this is the one API method using urlencoded data */) {
      httpRequestMessage.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    }
  }
  // ...remaining IClientMessageInspector methods...
}
```

As you can see, my problem in this case is that the IClientMessageInspector does not know from which method the message originated (so I can't look for a `UrlEncoded` attribute or something that tells me to use the urlencoded format in this case).

How would one add support for urlencoded messages in WCF without resorting to such hacks?

Ideally, I'd want to just decorate my method declaration with an attribute and hook some inspector, encoder, formatter or whatever into WCF that will find this attribute and urlencode the method's parameters instead of serializing them to JSON, eg.

```
[
  OperationContract,
  WebInvoke(UriTemplate = ""),
  OverrideMessageFormat(CustomMessageFormat.UrlEncoded) // like this
]
string Login(string user, string password);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form posts are not supported by default (content type is not supported) but WCF Samples provides two examples related to this topic:

- Custom [WebContentTypeMapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943479.aspx) to add support from new content types
- [Form Post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818241.aspx) - sample for HTML post but you can check how it works and make your own for JSON

There is also [WCFRestContrib](https://github.com/simplyaprogrammer/WcfRestContrib) project which offers support for form posts. Old [Rest Starter Kit](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2009/04/01/support-for-form-urlencoded-data-in-wcf-rest-services.aspx) also had support for form posts bur REST Starter Kit has never passed community preview. For last upcoming [Web-API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exposing%20a%20service%20over%20HTTP%20using%20HTTP%20Messages) (it will be the part of future WCF version) support working with forms as well. At the moment Web-API is available as CTP1.

Comment: I have taken a look at those projects and also done some work to make WCF support custom content types myself (via an IClientMessageFormatter that wrapped the original one) but while researching how I could automatically url-encode my messages I gave up when it looked like I had to clone the BodyWriteMessage class and lots of other stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the Web-API link, I'll give my project another go when Web-API releases!