# ASP.NET Google Signin: The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'

Tags: asp.net, web-services, post, xmlhttprequest, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google Signin using this page: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth
Where my token validation call is:

```
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'https://www.example.com/api/gtokensignin');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onload = function () {
            console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
        };
        xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);
```

I inspected the request via the [General] tab in Chrome developer console:

**General**

```
Request URL: https://www.example.com/api/gtokensignin
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 
Remote Address: 192.168.178.219:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

**Response headers**

```
cache-control: private
content-length: 2903
content-type: text/html
date: Thu, 01 Jul 2021 13:23:35 GMT
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```

**Request headers**

```
:authority: www.example.com
:method: POST
:path: /api/gtokensignin
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
content-length: 1220
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=ptesmo1fxwfcgv2cple6xdzi; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; G_AUTHUSER_H=0; _ga=GA1.1.1295181445.1624434076; __gads=ID=a5e2262ee1a99a43-23e99f1715c900bb:T=1624434076:RT=1624434076:S=ALNI_MZMMJEkUKSKcUUh9w9uH8_Z84lLAQ; _ga_MLNSQWJ4J5=GS1.1.1625123053.36.0.1625123053.0
dnt: 1
origin: https://www.example.com
referer: https://www.example.com/test2.aspx
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36
```

**Form data**

```
idtoken: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI2NiIsImtpZCI6IjExMmU0YjUyYWI4MzMwMTdkMzg1Y2UwZDBiNGM2MDU4N2VkMjU4NDIiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.S_ubEh_4IYhQTPVSye0-tma7pfhAu9xLOoKG5SoO08ZXhqpRxcvJu5C1E6luL9I-LYVLhUNHmplmtR0JJmg47x2lqFH_vwEEGmbhfdEBrEoCXShktxbfLu1p9WcK6MUFMZFT0q93Zp2PgPIfXp_caqqxMeAGEZfzWMK9ZmZhMfmTX_Ny2KlO4KJHR-FvY9Rv1XrcTrTiWfTclKFqpIvyWaUR-wk4srWpu1-riH5J9lz-VC-nmQAbWZw0kxD2DK0RjqsbeXJvPrrtjiCURM-s2b4tfvtyADRkgF2Nh9oOlsMJZRxKXoGNYsLoR0iYYcGbQm4NZGzVwmPj3pxtf1htEA
```

However, the server returns the following error:

> The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml'; 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.

Full error:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service. The exception message is 'The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml'; 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

**Iapi.vb**

```
<OperationContract()>
    <Web.WebInvoke(Method:="POST", ResponseFormat:=Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
UriTemplate:="gtokensignin")>
    Function gtokensignin(ByVal str As String) As Stream
```

I initially had `BodyStyle:=Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest` in the above code.
I also tried in `OperationContract()` to change the `BodyStyle=` to `BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped`, but that throws the same error.

I also tried changing the signature to:
`<Web.WebInvoke(Method:="POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,`
But then I get the error

> 'RequestFormat' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

**web.config**

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="Mysite.api">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding" contract="Mysite.Iapi" />
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpbind" contract="Mysite.Iapi" />
  </service>
</services>
```

When I go to check the resource availability via https://www.example.com/api.svc/help/operations/gtokensignin I see this page:
[image]

I already checked:

- [WCF service error - Incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. Expected message formats are 'Xml', 'Json'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123619/wcf-service-error-incoming-message-has-an-unexpected-message-format-raw-exp)
- [WCF request: "The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml'; 'Json'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325419/wcf-request-the-incoming-message-has-an-unexpected-message-format-raw-the-e)
- [The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407321/the-expected-message-formats-for-the-operation-are-xml-json)

**UPDATE 1**

I tried posting via JSON instead of a form post, but then I get the error:

```
The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the <a rel="help-page" href="https://www.example.com/api.svc/help">service help page</a> for constructing valid requests to the service. The exception message is 'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.String. End element 'root' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'idtoken' from namespace ''.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: 
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterDataContractMessageFormatter.ReadObject(Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on server error. It only accepts JSON or XML.
So try sending id_token as JSON like this.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://www.example.com/api/gtokensignin');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); // because we are sending json 

const data = {
    "idtoken": id_token,
};

xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

if you insist to send data as a form post look at this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6329148/5964792

**UPDATE 1**
Based on your update, Your server accepts the JSON request but it can not deserialize it to System.String because you are posting an object. To send a string as JSON try this

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://www.example.com/api/gtokensignin');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); // because we are sending json 

xhr.send(JSON.stringify(id_token));
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code example as I prefer it over a form post, but still get an error. Please see my update 1, could you have a look?

Comment: @Flo sure. The good news is your server accepts your JSON but it can not deserialize it to string. That was my bad I thought you need you to pass your token as an object. I updated my answer. I hope this one works. ;)

Comment: @Flo just pass id_token instead of data to JSON.stringify.

Comment: Just 1 more follow-up question that I hope you can help me with: how would I add multiple parameters to the xhr.send call? I tried something like this `        var params = {
            "idtoken": "dfdgldflgl4546l54jdfgd",
            "majorDimension": "ROWS",
            "values": [
                ["Hello World", "123", "456"]
            ],
        }
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));` but then I get the same error as before `End element 'root' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'range' from namespace `

Comment: @Flo Unfortunately I did not work with WCF so I can not give you a direct answer but I'm sure that you have to configure your WCF application to accept multiple arguments first. Currently, it accepts only one string. In web API project we create a class and properties inside that class are our parameters. I suggest you create another question and share your DataContract class. By the way, in your JSON you create a 2D array string for parameter values something like `public string[][] Values;`

Comment: @Flo Please mention me if you create another question. I would be glad to help.

Comment: appreciate that! Please see my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68397204/sending-multiple-parameters-xmlhttprequest-and-wcf