# Sending multiple parameters XMLHttpRequest and WCF

Tags: json, web-services, wcf, parameters, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send multiple parameters to a WCF service. Server side I log the incoming data. Where errors 1 and 2 are logged, but 3 and 4 are not. I tried debugging to be able to step through, but the client-side javascript call is not triggering my server-side code so I can step through.

What am I missing?

Request payload from Chrome Developer Console:

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'https://www.example.com/api/multipleparams');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ str: { "idtoken": "e46541", "lang": "dfgfdgfdg" } }));
    });

</script>   

<Runtime.Serialization.DataContract>
Public Class oAuthUserSigninDetails

    Private _idtoken As String
    <Runtime.Serialization.DataMember>
    Public Property idtoken As String
        Get
            Return _idtoken
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _idtoken = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _lang As String
    <Runtime.Serialization.DataMember>
    Public Property lang As String
        Get
            Return _lang
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _lang = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class



<OperationContract()>
<Web.WebInvoke(Method:="POST", ResponseFormat:=Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate:="multipleparams")>
Function multipleparams(ByVal str As oAuthUserSigninDetails) As Stream

Public Function multipleparams(ByVal str As oAuthUserSigninDetails) As Stream Implements Iapi.multipleparams
    LogError("1 multipleparams")
    LogError("2 str", str.ToString)
    LogError("3 idtoken", str.idtoken.ToString)
    LogError("4 lang", str.lang.ToString)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 3 and 4 are not logged because they have null values and ToString cause a null exception and since they are both string you don't need to use ToString at all.

When you accept a class as an argument in your OperationContract, I don't think you need to specify the argument name when you posting a JSON request.

```
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ "idtoken": "e46541", "lang": "dfgfdgfdg" }));
```